# How to integrate WinBox JS in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am playing with a javascript library called WinBoxJS. I know how to use this with plain JS. I am trying to use it in my Angular project. How can I do that?

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/winbox
```

I installed the winbox using npm. I also included the styles and scripts in the angular.json. I acn make it work if I use the JS and CSS files and add some script in index.html. But, I want it to Angular way. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> DISCLAIMER: The code below works for the current version of `winbox` i.e. **[`winbox@0.1.92`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winbox/v/0.1.92)**

You can use it in Angular by following the steps below:

1. Install winbox:

   `npm i winbox@0.1.92`
2. Add winbox CSS to your `styles.css`/`styles.scss`:

   `@import '~winbox/dist/css/winbox.min.css';`
3. Add the `winbox` bundle to your `angular.json` scripts at path - ( `projects.projectName.architect.build.options.scripts` ):

   ```
   "scripts": [
     "node_modules/winbox/dist/winbox.bundle.js"
   ]
   ```
4. Add a declaration for WinBox to your Component. The line below declares `WinBox` in `app.component.ts`:

   `declare const WinBox: any;`
5. Use WinBox as per their [Documentation here](https://nextapps-de.github.io/winbox/).

> Here's a **[Working Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-winbox-sample?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** for your ref.

Comment: On Stackblitz I'm getting "ERROR Error: WinBox is not defined".

Comment: Arrrggghhhh! It was working that day. Not sure why it's not today. But try the same steps on your local and it would work.

Comment: works with 0.2.0 too

Answer (score 0):

If you want, i created a wrapper for winbow which can be used in an angular project:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rbtechdev/angular-winbox